# How to load a tensorflow keras model saved with saved_model to use the predict function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sequential

I have a keras sequential model. I have saved that model using the command.

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, 'model')
```

Now it has the following folder structure,

[image: Now it has the following folder structure,]

Now I am loading the model using

```
model = tf.saved_model.load('model')
```

I also tried with

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model')
```

then I am trying to predict using

```
model.predict(padded_seq, verbose=0)
```

it is giving me error

```
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

how to use the predict on the model loaded. I have tried with h5 model, it worked fine. But my main use is with this kind of model which is throwing error.

Comment: If your h5 model worked just fine, why didn't you use that? What do you mean by "my main use is with this kind of model"?

Comment: @obr I am using triton inference server for inferencing. There we need saved_model format. That is why I am checking for help if I can get any help to work smoothly with saved_model. I dont know how to use h5 model at inference side.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the incorrect function to load your model (`tf.saved_model.load`); It does not return a Keras object (from [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load#:%7E:text=The%20object%20returned%20by%20tf.saved_model.load%20is%20not%20a%20Keras%20object%20(i.e.%20doesn%27t%20have%20.fit%2C%20.predict%2C%20etc.%20methods).)):

> The object returned by `tf.saved_model.load` is not a Keras object (i.e. doesn't have `.fit`, `.predict`, etc. methods).

You should be using [`tf.keras.models.load_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model) to load a Keras model.

Comment: Thanks @obr, I tried with load_model as well. It is also having same methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem with SavedModel models downloaded from TFHUB (example: InceptionV3), even loading it with `tf.keras.models.load_model()` returns a plain model (a sort of a basic generic model to allow back-compatibility) that does not have keras API (predict, fit, summary, build, etc) on top of it, the object type is:  `<tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x14a42ac2bcf8>`
If you want to use just the inference call (predict), you can call your model directly on data (__call__ method is defined) as follow:

```
model(padded_seq) # or model.__call__(padded_seq)
```

One workaround I have found to get the Keras API again is wrapping it inside a KerasLayer in a Sequential model as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer("saved/model/path")
])
model.build(<input_shape>)
```

Now the model supports all Keras API like predict, summary, etc, and this now should work:

```
model.predict(padded_seq, verbose=0)
```